# cannot create frame using python simplegui

Tags: python, user-interface

For the following code snippet:

```
import simplegui
message = "Welcome!"

def click():
  global message
  message = "Good job!"


def draw(canvas):
  canvas.draw_text(message, [50,112], 48, "Red")

frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 200)
frame.add_button("Click me", click)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
frame.start()
```

I'm getting error message on create_frame, "undefined variable from import:create_frame". 
Can anyone tell me what the problem is? 
simplegui is already imported and the code is given by a reputed university website.

Comment: I'm running it on a Eclipse pydev project

Comment: Coursera!! Can you show output of dir(simplegui)?

Comment: It's showing file not found, but I have already installed simplegui

Comment: It will not be there in PYTHONPATH. Refer http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html

Comment: shouldn't you do `frame = simplegui.GUI()` instead of `frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 200)`?

Comment: but draw handler won't work in GUI(), I need to implement it

Comment: @User: It is the custom module provided by coursera.org. If you want to see it in action, checkout http://www.codeskulptor.org/

Comment: could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: when I click the button, I should be able to display the message in a canvas

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're running into is that there are two libraries called simplegui. [The one on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegui) (the one that's giving you the error) is totally different from [the one for codeskulptor](http://activeed.rice.edu/comp160/docs.html) (the one for which you have example code). If you want to use codeskulptor's example code you'll have to run your code inside codeskulptor. If you want to run your code on your local computer you'll have to abandon the codeskulptor example code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use simplegui out side of codeskulptor you can download it with your terminal with the command: sudo pip install SimpleGUITk        Then you can import it with: import simpleguitk ... also just a heads up I've only found simplegui to work with python 2.7. Hope this helps!!